# Linux server C code stalls after receiving a signal

Tags: c, linux, server, signals, signal-handling

I have a problem with this simple server code, it works as expected until it receives a signal. 
For debug I print server and client file descriptors before calling select with the line:

```
fprintf(stderr,"server_socket_fd=%d client_socket_fd=%d fd_max=%d\n", server_socket_fd, client_socket_fd, fd_max);
```

When running normally it keeps printing

```
server_socket_fd=3 client_socket_fd=4 fd_max=4
```

but when it receives a signal it prints this line once

```
server_socket_fd=3 client_socket_fd=-1 fd_max=3
```

and then the program stalls.

Using GDB I put a breakpoint in the signal_handler and when it breaks I can't watch client_socket_fd variable, gdb says

```
No symbol "client_socket_fd" in current context.
```

And it doesn't return properly from the signal_handler function.. if I watch the back trace:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb7fdccf9 in ?? ()
#1  0xb7e26af3 in __libc_start_main (main=0x8048bdd <main>, argc=1, argv=0xbfffef24, init=0x8049a00 <__libc_csu_init>, 
    fini=0x8049a70 <__libc_csu_fini>, rtld_fini=0xb7fed160 <_dl_fini>, stack_end=0xbfffef1c) at libc-start.c:287
#2  0x08048b01 in _start ()
```

I don't know how to debug deeper.

This is the main code:

```
char receive_buf[2048];
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int server_socket_fd;
    int client_socket_fd = -1;
    int fd_max;

    struct sockaddr_in s_in;
    int one = 1;
    int status;

    fd_set readfds;

    int port;

    int next_option;
    const char* short_options = "hp:d:";
    const struct option long_options[] = {
        { "help",   0,  NULL,   'h'},
        { "port",   1,  NULL,   'p'},
        { "debug",   1,  NULL,   'd'},
        { NULL,     0,  NULL,   0}
    };

    program_name = argv[0];

    port = DEFAULT_PORT;
    debug = 0;

    do{
        next_option = getopt_long(argc, argv, short_options, long_options, NULL);
        switch(next_option){
            case 'h':
                print_usage(stdout, 0);
                break;
            case 'p':
                port = atoi(optarg);
                if((port < 0)||(port > 65535)){
                   fprintf(stderr, "Invalid port number (%d), using default: %d", port, DEFAULT_PORT);
                   port = DEFAULT_PORT;
                }
                break;
            case 'd':
                debug = atoi(optarg);
                if(debug < 0 || debug > 3)
                    debug = 0;
                break;
            case '?':
                print_usage(stderr, 1);
                break;
            case -1:
                break;
            default:
                abort();
        }
    }while(next_option != -1);

    /*************************  SIGNAL DEFINITIONS  ***************************/

    signal_action.sa_handler = (void *)signal_handler;
    sigemptyset(&signal_action.sa_mask);
    signal_action.sa_flags = SA_RESTART; // | SA_NOCLDSTOP;

    if(sigaction(SIGINT, &signal_action, NULL) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting SIGINT signal handler\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(sigaction(SIGTERM, &signal_action, NULL) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting SIGTERM signal handler\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(sigaction(SIGWINCH, &signal_action, NULL) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting SIGWINCH signal handler\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*  // ALSO TRIED WITH SIGNAL WITH SAME RESULT
    if(signal(SIGWINCH, signal_handler) == SIG_ERR){
        fprintf(stderr, "signal error\n");
        return 1;
    }
   */

    s_in.sin_family = PF_INET;
    s_in.sin_port = htons(port);
    s_in.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    if ((server_socket_fd = socket(s_in.sin_family, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == -1){
        perror("Error creating socket");
        return 1;
    }


    if(setsockopt(server_socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &one, sizeof(one)) == -1){
        perror("Error setting socket parameters");
        return 1;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    int x;
    x=fcntl(server_socket_fd,F_GETFL,0);              // Get socket flags
    fcntl(server_socket_fd,F_SETFL,x | O_NONBLOCK);   // Add non-blocking flag
    ////////////////////////////////////////////

    if(bind(server_socket_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &s_in, sizeof(s_in)) == -1){
        perror("Error binding socket");
        return 1;
    }


    if(listen(server_socket_fd, 1) == -1){
        perror("Error creating listening socket");
        return 1;
    }else{
        printf("Server (%d) listening on port %d\n", server_socket_fd, port);
    }

    memset(receive_buf, '\0', sizeof(receive_buf));
    gettimeofday(&t_print, NULL);

    while(1){

        // SERVER
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
        FD_SET(server_socket_fd, &readfds);
        fd_max = server_socket_fd;

        // ADD CLIENT IF CONNECTED
        if(client_socket_fd > 0){
            FD_SET(client_socket_fd, &readfds);
            if(client_socket_fd > server_socket_fd)
                fd_max = client_socket_fd;
        }

        // ADDED THIS FPRINTF TO CHECK VARIABLES  <----------------------------------
        fprintf(stderr,"server_socket_fd=%d client_socket_fd=%d fd_max=%d\n", server_socket_fd, client_socket_fd, fd_max);

        if(select(fd_max+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1){
            if(errno != EINTR){
                perror("select failed");
            }
        }

        // ACCEPT CLIENT
        if(FD_ISSET(server_socket_fd, &readfds)){

            struct sockaddr_in s_in;
            socklen_t len;

            len = sizeof(s_in);
            if((client_socket_fd = accept(server_socket_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &s_in, &len)) < 0){
                if(errno != EWOULDBLOCK){
                    perror("En accept");
                }
            }else
                printf("New client connected from %s\n", inet_ntoa(s_in.sin_addr));
        }

        // RECEIVE FROM CLIENT
        if(client_socket_fd > 0){
            if(FD_ISSET(client_socket_fd, &readfds)){
                handle_client(client_socket_fd);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
    }


int handle_client(int cl_fd){

    int n;

    n = recv(cl_fd, receive_buf, sizeof(receive_buf) - 1, MSG_DONTWAIT);
    if(n == 0){
        fprintf(stderr,"--------------> DEBUG: handle_client:client %d closed connection\n", cl_fd);
    }else if(n < 0){
        if(errno == EAGAIN){
            return 0;
        }else{
            fprintf(stderr,"--------------> DEBUG: handle_client: recv ERROR: client %d closed connection (errno: %d : %s)\n", cl_fd, errno, strerror(errno));
            memset(receive_buf, 0, sizeof(receive_buf));
            return -1;
        }
    }else{
        receive_buf[n] = '\0';
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", receive_buf);
    }
        return 0;
   }
void signal_handler(int sig){

    switch(sig){

    case SIGINT:
        exit_properly(0);
        break;
    case SIGTERM:
        exit_properly(1);
        break;
    case SIGABRT:
        fprintf(stderr, "SIGABRT signal received\n");
        break;

    case SIGWINCH:
        fprintf(stderr, "\33[2J");
        fflush(stdout);
        break;

    default:
        fprintf(stderr, "Unhandled signal %d received\n",sig);
        break;
    }
}
```

I don't know what else can I do for debugging this issue and I am stuck. Any help will be very appreciated!

EDITED:

This is the strace output when it fails, as you can see it prints (and select uses) the right file descriptors and then, after the signal occurs, the client_socket_fd is wrong because accept fails with EAGAIN. I have commented the exit_properly calls and also the signal handling for SIGTERM and SIGINT. For the SIGWINH signal I do nothing, just return.

STRACE output:

```
write(2, "server_socket_fd=3 client_socket"..., 47server_socket_fd=3 client_socket_fd=4 fd_max=4
) = 47
select(5, [3 4], NULL, NULL, NULL)      = ? ERESTARTNOHAND (To be restarted if no handler)
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
sigreturn() (mask [])                   = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
accept(3, 0xbf981e7c, [16])             = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
write(2, "server_socket_fd=3 client_socket"..., 48server_socket_fd=3 client_socket_fd=-1 fd_max=3
) = 48
select(4, [3], NULL, NULL, NULL)        = ? ERESTARTNOHAND (To be restarted if no handler)
--- SIGWINCH {si_signo=SIGWINCH, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
sigreturn() (mask [])                   = -1 EINTR (Interrupted system call)
accept(3, 0xbf981e7c, [16])             = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
write(2, "server_socket_fd=3 client_socket"..., 48server_socket_fd=3 client_socket_fd=-1 fd_max=3
) = 48
select(4, [3], NULL, NULL, NULL
```

The signal_handler now:

```
void signal_handler(int sig){

    switch(sig){
    /*
    case SIGINT:
        exit_properly(0); //sigint_flag = 1;
        break;
    case SIGTERM:
        exit_properly(1); //sigterm_flag = 1;
        break;

*/
    case SIGWINCH:
        //sigwinch_flag = 1;
/*
        fprintf(stderr, "\33[2J");
        fflush(stdout);
    */
        break;

    default:
        //fprintf(stderr, "Unhandled signal %d received\n",sig);
        break;
    }
}
```

Also tried without the `SA_RESTART` flag... same result...  ?: /

Comment: `fprintf()` is not async-safe.

Comment: Which specific signal does your program get when the issue occurs ? Even just for debugging ,you should not use fprintf() in the signal handler,  it can deadlock your program (which could be the cause the issue you are seeing). Use e.g. write() directly, but do not use any functions that operate on a FILE* or are otherwise unsafe to call in a signal handler. You might also get some clues to what your program is doing if you run it with the strace tool (e.g. strace -f ./myprogram) , that will tell you which syscall you got stuck at

Comment: what is exit_properly? Just a thought, Maybe setting SA_RESTART is not a good idea. if you get a signal it might affect your select statement to continue indefinitely by waiting forever. meanwhile exit_properly might wait for this select to die for some reason for graceful shutdown (might explain the missing symbols). just a wild guess here

Comment: well my guess is: signal ->exit_properly -> "no exit && server socket dies" -> accept fails and -1 returned  to client_socket_fd -> fd set is empty -> stuck on select indefinitely.

Comment: @nos that should not happen since I ask recv to read up to (sizeof(receive_buf) - 1)

Comment: @nos It happens with any defined signal. I have comment out SIGTERM and SIGINT so it only triggers the signal_handler for SIGWINCH. I have also  comment out the fprintf in signal_handler. Same result. I will try strace tool now. Thanks!

Comment: @Aviv, your guess is rigth in that accept fails (with EAGAIN) but not in exit, just because entering in the signal_handler (where I do nothing)... I don't know the reason. I am gonna use a temp variable to get the accept return and check the EAGAIN error, so I dont update the client_socket_fd if it is not ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select()` will be interrupted by a signal, return -1, and set errno to EINTR, but your code fails to handle this.
Even if you install a signal handler with the `SA_RESTART` , there are still a number of system calls that will be interrupted, return an error condition and set errno to `EINTR`.

See the  "Interruption of system calls and library functions by signal handlers" 
 section at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html/

If select fails, your code goes on to check the `readfds` like this:

```
if(FD_ISSET(server_socket_fd, &readfds)){
```

However, if select() fails, the `fd_set` variables you pass to it are in an indeterministic state, you should not rely on their values.

Instead, if select fails you should just re-start your loop with e.g. a continue statement like so:

```
  if(select(fd_max+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL) == -1){
        if(errno != EINTR){
            perror("select failed");
           //Might be severe enough to quit your program... 
        }
       continue; 
    }
```

Comment: you are right, I shouldn't go forward if select fails. I will update the code. Thanks!  (the link is broken)

Comment: Very nice insight, missed that while reading the linux man pages

Comment: @japjap tell us if this answer resolved the signal EAGIAN issue, im interested

Comment: @Aviv, yes, this also solves the issue. The main thing is not to trust accept's return value and check it before updating client_socket_fd variable. I resolved it with a temp variable but nos is right in that there is no point in checking the file descriptor set with FD_ISSET is the select failed since it may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution just using a temporally variable.

I don't know why, but signals made select flags the server_socket_fd to be read (IF SOMEONE KNOWS WHY PLEASE SHARE), just like if a client would be trying to connect, and accept returned EAGAIN error, so the client_socket_fd variable was written to -1.

I solved this simply using a temp variable (ret) instead of assigning the accept result directly to client_socket_fd:

```
// ACCEPT CLIENT
        if(FD_ISSET(server_socket_fd, &readfds)){

            struct sockaddr_in s_in;
            socklen_t len;

            len = sizeof(s_in);
            if((ret = accept(server_socket_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &s_in, &len)) < 0){
                if(errno != EWOULDBLOCK){
                    perror("En accept");
                }
            }else{
                client_socket_fd = ret;
                printf("New client connected from %s\n", inet_ntoa(s_in.sin_addr));
            }
        }
```

Only update variables when you are sure they are OK... lesson learned!  :)

Comment: first, your error checking in this function should also check for EAGAIN and EWOULDBLOCK since both of them might come up. second, it seems from your code you handle a client and then wait for the next one. if so, you should close the socket manually after every handle_client call.
now you are just continue reading the old client_socket_fd.
 those errors you are getting in the strace should happen only when using  non blocking socket. but you dont. maybe it should be explicitly unset?

Comment: @Aviv this is a quick a dirty code for testing a client so I don't care about portability and in my system EAGAIN is, in fact, a define to EWOULDBLOCK. For the same reason, the server just allows one client

Comment: Fair enough. Jus thought maybe the EAGAIN is fired because the socket aint closed. It's closed externally and the signal might prevent the server close it, yielding in resource not available. Just a guess. Closing it manually might override it